# how to check for duplicates in random array?

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I have an array of 4 numbers and I'm having trouble checking for duplicates. I had the impression that if i randomize numbers for arr[i], then for arr[j], I can compare them for duplicates and randomize again if true. How do I go about checking that element of the array is not repeated/duplicated?

```
int arr[4];
srand(time(0));

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    arr[i] = rand() % 10;
    for(int j=i+1; j<4; j++)
    {
        arr[j] = rand() % 10;
        if(arr[j] == arr[i])
        {
            arr[i] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
cout << arr[i] << endl;
```

Comment: You have 'sorting' in the tag, but none in the code. It is also unclear what the purpose of [re-]randomizing the array would be. In any case, I believe the term/approach you are looking for is "random shuffle" - this is how a PowerBall lottery or shuffling a deck of cards works. (And looking for such will lead to relevant questions/answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another trick to *avoid* using `goto` all together is to reverse `i`   `for(int j=0; j < i ; j++)  if (arr[j] == arr[i]) i--` , when in the check for duplicates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;



int main(void)
{
      const int size=100 ;
      int  arr[100] ;
      int i=0;

      srand(time(0));

      for ( i=0;i<size;i++)   {
          arr[i]=rand() % size;
          for(int j=0; j < i ; j++)  if (arr[j] == arr[i]) i--; 
      }
       cout<<"   \n\n\n ";


      // Loop to display the array arr[ ]
      for (  i=0;i<size;i++) cout<<""<<arr[i]<<"\t";

      cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
      cin.ignore();
      cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 91     71      14      65      12      25      64      98      83      28
99      9       5       0       89      36      95      55      73      90
78      2       52      70      39      63      17      50      7       58
34      84      40      51      20      31      38      32      35      49
61      66      72      92      6       59      41      13      22      23
81      56      1       16      21      62      57      10      11      54
77      86      76      93      4       96      8       33      94      67
29      48      15      82      97      37      26      46      43      80
68      85      60      30      42      53      18      69      45      88
47      79      75      44      24      27      74      3       19      87

Press any key to continue
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you are checking the contents of the array above your current index i, which havent even been written yet, you need to check the contents below the index i to find a new value that you have not stored yet.

The second issue with your code is, that it can only generate a new random number once if it already existed. The program never checks if the second alternative random number also already exists.

This should be correct:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    boolean exists = true;
    while (exists) {
        exists = false;
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;

        for (int j=0; j<i && !exists; j++)
            if (arr[j] == arr[i])
                exists = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach . You are using a loop for when j=i+1 till j<4 while if the value of i is less than j then the loop is of no use .

```
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        for(j=0,j<i-1;j++)
      {
        if (arr[j] == arr[i])
        {
            arr[i] = rand() % 10;
        }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 4;
    int arr[N];

    std::srand( std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t j;
        do
        {
            arr[i] = std::rand() % 10;

            j = 0;
            while ( j < i && arr[j] != arr[i] ) j++;
        } while ( j != i );
    }

    for ( int x : arr ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
5 9 6 7
```